# How can I squeeze singleton dimension after getting a SubArray?

Tags: c#, ilnumerics

I have a two dimensional array 'v' representing a list of vectors
And I have a three dimensional array 'a' that represents a list of matrices

```
ILArray v = counter(2, 3);
ILArray a = counter(2, 3, 3);
```

Now I want to take a subarray of both and do a matrix multiply:

```
ILArray av = multiply(a[1,full,full], v[1,full]);
```

It will complain that the dimensions do not match and this is because the dimensions of `a[1,full,full]` is `(1,3,3)` and of `v[1,full]` is `(1,3)`. In other words, the subarrays contain a singleton dimension. In matlab I can remove these singleton dimensions with squeeze(). But how can I do that in ILNumerics?

---

I just discovered that if the singleton dimension are trailing, then they are automagically removed by ILNumerics, so this works:

```
ILArray v = counter(3, 2);
ILArray a = counter(3, 3, 2);
ILArray av = multiply(a[full,full, 1], v[full, 1]);
```

Also, `a[full,full,1]` has dimension `(3,3)`  and not `(3,3,1)`.

Does that mean that ILNumerics does not support non-trailing singleton dimensions? In other words, does not support strided arrays in calculations but only contiguous ones? That would be rather restrictive to say the least.

Thanks,
Luc

Comment: What do you mean by "support strided arrays"? We basically expect all arrays to be dense. The subarray you derive by a[1,full,full] is also a dense (or contiguous) array. As you said, it only carries a singleton dimension. But this does not open up any "holes" as I would expect from the term 'stride' ? Please clarify further.

Comment: Luke, if the solution by numbers303 is working for you, please mark the answer as correct. Thanks!

Comment: Strided arrays are indeed arrays where the elements are not on contigues memory addresses. They happen alot in numerical code.

Comment: For instance assume you have a very large contigues two dimensional matrix in memory and want to apply an vector wise operation on a column or a row. If you take a column SubArray it returns a contigues vector, but if you take a row SubArray it returns a vector where each item is spaced at a regular distance in memory. Such a subarray is called strided.

Comment: To make both operations efficient, most numerical libraries such as MKL and IPP supports many matrix and vector operation with strided arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn’t a simple reshape do the trick?

```
ILArray<int> I = ILMath.counter<int>(1,1,ILMath.size(5,4,3));

I
<Int32> [5,4,3]
    [0]: (:,:,0)
    [1]:          1          6         11         16
    [2]:          2          7         12         17
    [3]:          3          8         13         18
    [4]:          4          9         14         19
    [5]:          5         10         15         20
    [6]: (:,:,1)
    [7]:         21         26         31         36
    [8]:         22         27         32         37
    [9]:         23         28         33         38
    [10]:         24         29         34         39
    [11]:         25         30         35         40
    [12]: (:,:,2)
    [13]:         41         46         51         56
    [14]:         42         47         52         57
    [15]:         43         48         53         58
    [16]:         44         49         54         59
    [17]:         45         50         55         60

I["0;:;:"]
<Int32> [1,4,3]
    [0]: (:,:,0)
    [1]:          1          6         11         16
    [2]: (:,:,1)
    [3]:         21         26         31         36
    [4]: (:,:,2)
    [5]:         41         46         51         56

ILMath.reshape(I["0;:;:"],4,3)
<Int32> [4,3]
    [0]:          1         21         41
    [1]:          6         26         46
    [2]:         11         31         51
    [3]:         16         36         56
```

Having a `squeeze` function would be more convenient. You may open a feature request on the bugtracker in order to have it implemented in one of the next releases: http://ilnumerics.net/mantis

Comment: But according to the documentation a reshapes makes a deep copy of the data. If your matrix is really big that this is a performance penalty.

Comment: What I would like to happen is that squeeze returns an array that shares the same memory but has a strided layout. If I then perform an operation, the library should dispatch to one of the strided functions in MKL, or make a deep copy when that is not possible.

Comment: Shall I include all this in a feature request?

Comment: As an example, the MKL function `copy` that copys values of one vector to another has two increments:

`scopy(n, x, incx, y, incy)`

that can be used when both vector have different strides and are not contigues. Almost all BLAS functions support this.

Comment: @Luke reshape does not copy any data. Only the dimension descriptor is exchanged which is basically very cheap. Can you point me to the documentation, where you have found the (wrong) description?

Comment: There has been such a feature as 'strided arrays' in the very first version of ILNumerics. The problem and the reason it has been removed: It increases (internal library) complexity significantly and the cases where this really pays of are rather rare. Furthermore, in a future version, ILNumerics will introduce automatic lazy evaluation which will bring the same (and even higher) profit performance wise.